# jQuery/Ajax get file from server containing php and html code

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a website where there are various category buttons on top of the page, and the content of each category is stored in other files that are called and printed on the screen using jQuery's ajax.
Initially, there is no content shown, and you can only see category buttons. When you click a button, it will asynchronously get the content from other file, which is written in php and html. 
How can you achieve this? Each of the content files include HTML and php like:

```
<div class="categoryX">
    <?php foreach($contents as $content): ">
        <!--more code in both php and html-->
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

This code prints various content for each category, but each of them has php variables and HTML code mixed. I don't know what the dataType is going to be in this case. Also, is it possible to read in such files?

Comment: so the response for the ajax is in html? how does `$contents` set? *Also, is it possible to read in such files* -- if you mean take a html and print it somewhere, it's possible.

Comment: That part is actually another question. The response file contains both php and html code. In that case, I am not sure if I should make a file in .php or.html extension. Also, the problem is the php code contains information from ANOTHER .php file. It is like this: there is a .php file which contains a class and its objects (=contents of each category). The response file I want to call using ajax is using the objects. How could you possibly do this?

Comment: In .php file that contains class and object instantiation, I stored all objects created inside an array called $contents. So like, $contents = array($object1, $object2, ..... );

Comment: well, i'd [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the other `.php` file in the `html` mixed `.php` file - it will be rendered into `.html` in the end (when being served to user or jquery, basically any http request). then use the retrieved `.html`

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could mark your comments as the best solution.